# Why do I get a syntax error for "LEFT [OUTER] JOIN"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have 3 tables:

- Student with these columns: Id(pk), FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, GroupId(fk) ;
- Subject with these columns: Id(pk), Name ;
- Student_Grade_Subject with these columns: StudentId, SubjectId(composed pk), Grade(int) ;

So my question is how would a query that returns the mean of each student's grades look? I know that I have to do an outer join since not all the students have grades.

This is what I've tried so far but I get "Incorrect syntax near OUTER".

```
 select s.Id, MEAN(Grade) from dbo.Student s , dbo.Student_Grade_Subject
 sgs LEFT [OUTER] JOIN dbo.Student_Grade_Subject on s.id =
 sgs.StudentId group by s.Id;
```

Comment: the square brackets in the syntax diagram indicate an optional element of the syntax. remove them from the actual query.

Comment: and don't use old-style joins nor mix the old-style joins with the more appropriate JOIN syntax.

Comment: what is the more appropriate JOIN syntax?

Comment: An ANSI-92 `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` (which is what you have here).

Comment: You used old-style join between Student and Student_Grade_Subject while using JOIN with Student_Grade_Subject yet again. Start over. Give your tables short and meaningful aliases - all tables should have them, not just some of them. You are learning bad habits and contributing to your own (and others) confusion.

Comment: I've edited your title to focus the question on why you're getting a syntax error, rather than the broad question of "what query should I write" (as others have said, we won't do your homework for you).

Comment: @SMor Looking at the query, I don't think they intended to use an old-style join, or an unaliased table, they just misunderstood where tables get named.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's format the SQL better; this is always a good idea to read your own code, and a **really** good idea when showing it to other people:

```
SELECT 
    s.Id,
    MEAN(Grade)
FROM
    dbo.Student s,
    dbo.Student_Grade_Subject sgs
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN
    dbo.Student_Grade_Subject 
    ON s.id = sgs.StudentId
GROUP BY
    s.Id;
```

Now let's see where you went wrong:

- Separating tables with commas is an old-fashioned way of writing joins; you might see it in very old examples, but will never need it in new code. `dbo.Student, dbo.Student_Grade_Subject` means take *every* row in Student, and match it to *every* row in Student_Grade_Subject (a "cross join") unless told otherwise by a `WHERE` clause.
- When syntax examples put things in square brackets, they're just telling you that word is optional (there's lots of optional words in SQL, in an attempt to make it read like natural language), not that you have to write the square brackets in the query. So you can write either `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, but not `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`.
- Because you've got the comma-join as well as the left join, you've actually got *three* tables in this query: `dbo.Student`, the `dbo.Student_Grade_Subject` you aliased as `sgs`, and the second `dbo.Student_Grade_Subject` without an alias. Your `ON` condition mentions the comma-joined table, not the left joined one, so isn't going to do what you want.

Fixing this all up, we get this:

```
SELECT 
    s.Id,
    MEAN(Grade)
FROM
    dbo.Student s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Student_Grade_Subject sgs
    ON s.id = sgs.StudentId
GROUP BY
    s.Id;
```

As a good habit, I suggest writing `MEAN(Grade)` as `MEAN(sgs.Grade)`; as queries get more complex, it's useful to be able to see at a glance which table each column is coming from.